# $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\cos\left(2\pi\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^a\right)\right]^{x^2},a\in R$

Tags: limits

Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\cos\left(2\pi\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^a\right)\right]^{x^2}=e^{-2\pi^2 a^2},a\in R$

---

Let $x=\frac{1}{t}$
$L=\lim_{t\to 0}\left[\cos\left(2\pi\left(\frac{1}{1+t}\right)^a\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{t^2}}$

This is in $1^{\infty}$ form.So i applied $e^{g(x)\times (f(x)-1)}$
$L=e^{\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t^2}\times \left[\cos\left(2\pi\left(\frac{1}{1+t}\right)^a\right)-1\right]}=e^{\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-2}{t^2}\times \sin^2\left(\pi\left(\frac{1}{1+t}\right)^a\right)}$

$L=e^{\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{-2}{t^2}\times \pi\left(\frac{1}{1+t}\right)^a\times \pi\left(\frac{1}{1+t}\right)^a}$

This power $a$ is creating problem.From here on ,i am stuck and could not solve.Please help me reach the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:$$\\\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\cos\left(2\pi\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^a\right)\right]^{x^2}\\=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\left(x^2\ln\cos2\pi\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^a\right)}\\=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x^2\ln\cos2\pi e^{a\ln\frac{x}{1+x}}}\\=\lim_{y\to0}e^{\frac1{y^2}\ln\cos2\pi e^{a\ln\frac1{1+y}}}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Write $x=(x+1)-1$, then use the approximation $(1+t)^a\simeq1+at$ when

$t=\dfrac1{x+1}\to0$, followed by $\cos(2\pi+u)=\cos u$, and $\cos u\simeq1-\dfrac{u^2}2$ when $u\to0$.